# Invalid object name 'dbo.tbl_user' after running sql(azure) query from nodejs app

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

I am getting error Invalid object name `dbo.tbl_user`.while running a query on the Azure database from a nodejs app.My code which runs is following.

```
 const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(DatabaseConfig.config);

    pool.connect().then(function () {
        //6.
        debugger;
        var request = new sql.Request(pool);
        //7.
        request.query("select * from [dbo].[tbl_user]").then(function (recordSet) {
            debugger;
            console.log(recordSet);
            sql.close();
        }).catch(function (err) {
            //8.
            debugger;
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
        });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //9.
        debugger;
        console.log(err);
    });
```

My connection string is :

```
 config: {
    server: 'azureserver',
    options: {
        database: 'cccc',
        encrypt: true,
        port: 1433
    },
    user: 'ccc',
    password: 'ccccc'
}
```

what is the mistake I am doing here? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: try changing the case of tbl_user to tbl_User and see if it works

Comment: same issue occurs for other tables also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code on my side but did not reproduce your issue.

***Here is my test code:***

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    server: '***.database.windows.net',
    database: '***',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    options: {
        database: '***',
        encrypt: true,
        port: 1433
    }
}

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);

pool.connect().then(function () {
    //6.
    debugger;
    var request = new sql.Request(pool);
    //7.
    request.query("select * from [dbo].[Student]").then(function (recordSet) {
        debugger;
        console.log(recordSet);
        sql.close();
    }).catch(function (err) {
        //8.
        debugger;
        console.log(err);
        sql.close();
    });
}).catch(function (err) {
    //9.
    debugger;
    console.log(err);
});
```

***Query result on the portal:***

[image]

***Run query.js :***

[image]

You need to make sure the table name is correct, it's not related to spelling case.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @SatheeshM Ok. You could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum who uses node.js to access sql server.